# Loading bar in Page

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

I want to implement a page where in a single page, half of the data is getting loaded immediately, but for one column I have to wait for sometimes for getting the response and once the response comes. I have to display the content in that column. Everything is working for me and I have added the loader.gif also because user will not think that they are not getting any response.

The problem I am facing is, it is using loading gif for whole page instead of displaying only for the loading content. I want loader.gif should get displayed in the bottom somewhere where cancel button is there till that one column is getting the response and rest other field should come immediately.

I have used:

Body part -

```
<div class="se-pre-con"></div>
```

CSS -

```
.no-js #loader { display: none;  }
.js #loader { display: block; position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0; }
.se-pre-con {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url(resources/images/loading.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}
```

javascript -

```
$(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle and share

Answer (score 0):

It seems your are new at `css`. I make `jQuery` functions for you ;)

```js
$(function(){
 $('.box').click(function(){
   $(this).loaderToggle();
  });
});

// code u need

jQuery.fn.loaderOn = function(...args){
 this.loaderInstall().find('.se-pre-con').fadeIn(...args);
    
  return this;
}
jQuery.fn.loaderOff = function(...args){
 this.find('.se-pre-con').fadeOut(...args);
  
  return this;
}
jQuery.fn.loaderToggle = function(...args){
 this.loaderInstall().find('.se-pre-con').fadeToggle(...args);
  
  return this;
}
jQuery.fn.loaderInstall = function(){
 if(!this.loaderInstalled()) {
   this.append($('<div class="se-pre-con"></div>').hide());
  }
  
  return this;
}
jQuery.fn.loaderDestroy = function(){
 this.removeClass('loader-container').find('.se-pre-con').remove();
  
  return this;
}
jQuery.fn.loaderInstalled = function(){
 this.addClass('loader-container');
 
  return !!this.find('.se-pre-con').length;
}
```

```css
/* 
code you need
*/

.loader-container {
  position: relative;
}

.se-pre-con {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/09b24e31234507.564a1d23c07b4.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
  background-size: contain;
  z-index: 9999;
}


/* 
just for grid
*/

body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
        grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #444;
    }

    .box {
        background-color: #444;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 150%;

    }

    .a {
        grid-column: 1 / 3;
        grid-row: 1;
    }
    .b {
        grid-column: 3 ;
        grid-row: 1 / 3;
    }
    .c {
        grid-column: 1 ;
        grid-row: 2 ;
    }
    .d {
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-row: 2;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all thanks @Guja1501 for such quick response, 
Just for the curiosity:  function(...args) works for what? 
Although it didn't work as per my requirement. My requirement was, onload not onclick, so I made changes according to that only.